# How to setup CDN CloudFront for Refile gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I've got my application working fine with Refile and uploading images to S3. I've read that you should put a CDN in front of the application to make it more efficient and secure.

Is there any place I can read to set it up properly? I've look at the github repo and tried following the instructions but I feel like I did it wrong.

This is what I did:

1. Create a AWS CloudFront distribution where origin domain name points to my S3 instance (bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com).
2. Create a CNAME with Route 53 to add a custom domain name "cdn.mydomain.com" that points to the CloudFront domain name "xxx.cloudfront.net".
3. Go to my /config/initializers/refile.rb and added the line: 
   Refile.cdn_host = "https://cdn.myappname.com".
4. Commit and push to Heroku
5. All my image links are broken now.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I noticed your cdn_host starts with https.  Did you associate an ssl certificate with your distribution for cdn.myappname.com?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this was to put a put Cloudfront in front of the whole site and not the bucket itself.

1. Create AWS CloudFront distribution setting the origin to my domain (www.example.com)
2. Create CNAME (cloud.example.com) that points to xxx.cloudfront.net
3. Go to config/environments/production.rb and add the line `config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://cloud.example.com'`
4. Go to config/initializers/refile.rb and add the line `Refile.cdn_host = 'http://cloud.example.com'`